# How to customize post block in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

i want to **edit** a block in wordpress theme.

I want to make a custom wp:image block and transform it from this:

[image: Step 1]

To something like this:

[image]

I searched for guides on this topic, but what I needed was not there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since `5.5` lazy loading is native to WordPress.

As stated in the [Make article from the 15 of july 2020](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2020/07/14/lazy-loading-images-in-5-5/).

> By default, WordPress will add `loading="lazy"` to all img tags that have `width` and `height` attributes present.

WordPress is using the [`wp_filter_content_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_filter_content_tags/) function coupled with `wp_img_tag_add_loading_attr ()` to handle when to add the `loading="lazy"` attribute:

> Filters specific tags in post content and modifies their markup
> Adds loading attribute to an img HTML tag.

If you're adding your image through blocks, it will automatically add width and height to make it lazy loading able.